# Aggregate child records with multiple values

Tags: apex, aggregate

I need to find the max date of 2 field on Object__c
Structure
Object_A is parent
Object__B is junction object where Object__A and Object__C are lookup fields
Object__c is object that has the date fields where I need to find the max value of 2 fields.
There may be multiple Object__C records.

When an Object__C is update I query for the Object__B record where the Object__C record is housed and then query all of the Object__C records.  I think I have this part ok.  My question is how do I get all of the Object__C records into an Aggregate query and find the max date of the 2 fields?  I will be pushing the dates to Object__A.  Or is using an Aggregate query the incorrect approach?

```
List<AggregateResult> permitAggrDateList = [
        SELECT Id, MAX(Rec_Date_c), MAX(Submit_Date__c)
        FROM Object__C
        WHERE Id IN : ?????
        GROUP BY Id
        ORDER BY MAX(Rec_Date__c), MAX(Submit_Date__c) DESC
];
```

Comment: to be honest hard to understand the question. I would suggest use Parent__c, Child__c, Junction__c

Comment: another point if you have Junction then you can't have Parent and Child, because you have many-to-many)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using aggregate functions to do this is a valid approach (not the only approach). A few things to note though:

- `GROUP BY Id` (by the Id field of the SObject your query is based on) makes the query worthless

  - no records would be grouped together
  - so `MAX()` would just return the value of each individual record
  - all of the downsides of `AggregateResult` with none of the benefits
- Using aggregate functions is useful on child records (where you can group by a relationship field), and much less so on parent records

If you want to do this using SOQL, your query should be based on `Object_B` instead.

It is possible to use aggregate functions on related data, which is very helpful for trying to aggregate data using a junction object (i.e. for a many-to-many relationship).

So with that knowledge in hand, the requirements for your query look like:

- Based on `Object_B`
- Using `MAX(Object_C__r.Rec_Date_c)` and `MAX(Object_C__r.Submit_Date_c)`
- With a filter to grab all junction object records `Object_C__c IN :triggeredObjectCIds`
- Grouping by `Object_A__c`

Comment: Derek. Thank you for the thorough response.  I added the 'Id' to group by because I was getting an error when trying to save the class.  I need to group by a field if I am to use the 'order by'.   What should I be 'grouping by'?  Or do I not need the 'order by'?

Comment: @Phuc Like I said in my answer, you need to be querying on Object_B, and grouping by Object_A__c (or whatever the relationship field is).

Comment: I should have reread your comment.  Thanks